# Change default language for a LinkedServer query

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am struggling with setting language for a query that runs on linked server:

```
select * from OPENQUERY([my_linkedserver_here], 'select @@LANGID, @@LANGUAGE, * from myView')
```

where [myView] is a view that requires @@LangID variable to display data with a proper language. I can't use 'set language' option inside query because it returns error that no data was found/returned or user has no priviledges to do it (I tried it with [sa]). Setting language outside OPENQUERY doesn't help either. Its always us_english set.

Any hint? 
Thanks, Ray

Comment: I guess you could configure the language of the user of the linked server

Comment: I thought in the same way, but there is collation only to be set :\